# Computer will boot but monitor doesn't turn on until lock screen

Tags: boot, display, bios

I need to access my bios settings as I need to enable virtualization, but when I turn my computer on, (monitor is on stand by) the monitor only displays anything once the computer is at the lock screen. I tried turning my monitor on 2 seconds before I booted on my computer and I also tried to turn the monitor on while the computer was booting, but both times the monitor said "No signal." What can I do?

My computer runs Windows 8 with an Intel i7 4790K processor, 16GB RAM, Asus 24" VE248H moniter with a 750GB hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your monitor is taking a while to "notice" the signal and turn itself on. Two possible solutions for you:

1. It may take some trial and error, but try to figure out what keystroke gets you into your BIOS settings. On most PCs, it's F1 or Delete (not Backspace). Sometimes it's F12. You may be able to press the Pause/Break key to halt the POST routine so the screen can catch up.
2. Borrow a screen from a different machine that has a faster wake-up cycle and watch for messages at bootup. If you get a graphical splash screen instead of text, try pressing Escape or Tab.

Comment: To access the bios, my motherboard requires F2 to be pressed, and I have tried that with no luck. I'll try to get another monitor, but is there any other option you can think of?

Comment: Ah, so no display, even if you successfully make it into the BIOS setup program? Sounds like your monitor can't display whatever resolution your motherboard outputs before the OS takes over. A different monitor may be your only solution here.

Comment: No, I can't make it to the bios screen. The first thing I ever see on my computer is the lock screen. But, I need to access the bios, but I don't see a startup screen.