# My monitor won't turn on until it gets to the lock screen?

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, dvi

When I use a **HDMI** connection it works great. It loads the MSI boot screen (which gives me the option to enter the **BIOS**) and then it loads windows. Basically everything you would expect from a normal computer.

But when I switch it to **DVI** connection my monitor **DOESN'T** turn on until it reaches the locked screen.

My monitor is a **ASUS VG248QE**.

My graphics card is a **GTX 970**.

I've tried the solutions suggested here with no luck: [Computer will boot but monitor doesn't turn on until lock screen](https://superuser.com/questions/797692/computer-will-boot-but-monitor-doesnt-turn-on-until-lock-screen)

Since this is an ongoing issue I think it should be addressed and solved.

Comment: If your GTX 970 has two DVI ports, try the other one. Otherwise, you’re out of luck. It’s up to the GPU to properly decide which is the primary monitor.

Comment: Do you happen to have multiple monitors (even switched off), or anything that might appear to be a monitor, attached? I've seen something similar happen because the startup sequence isn't always aware of secondary monitors, and your system might have decided that a different port is a primary monitor.

Comment: I only have 1 monitor. Just one

Comment: @Larvitar Anything at all (cables, adapters) plugged into the other ports? What's your motherboard?

Comment: No. And i have a z97- gd65 motherboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Bios setup for GPU settings on boot.

DVI is on a plugin PCI video card not but onboard is still enabled by the BIOS until windows is loaded then Windows uses the correct port.

If you see anything relevant ..eg change video source Hybrid ( use both onboard and card) to PCI only .

You will have to change video port cable to onboard VGA or something to see setup (Del or Esc etc)

Then shut down swap cable and test.